# How to use packages directly in `allowUnfreePredicate`?

Tags: nix

The manual [suggests](https://nixos.org/manual/nixpkgs/stable/#sec-allow-unfree) allowing packages by name:

```
{
  allowUnfreePredicate = pkg: builtins.elem (lib.getName pkg) [
    "roon-server"
    "vscode"
  ];
}
```

Is it possible to instead do this with packages directly? I tried the following:

```
{
  allowUnfreePredicate = pkg:
    builtins.elem pkg [
      pkgs.hplip
    ];
}
```

That doesn't seem to work:

> error: Package ‘hplip-3.22.6’ in /nix/store/lh7i6yw570nkw49byrgjbrna9az3ryy7-nixos-22.05/nixos/pkgs/misc/drivers/hplip/default.nix:268 has an unfree license (‘unfree’), refusing to evaluate.

Is the `pkg` object not the same as the entries in `pkgs`, does `builtins.elem` not treat complex objects as equal, or is something else going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](https://gitlab.com/engmark/root/-/blob/918c8f98b9adc521e4e04a8a7f4f8595c63e46e8/configuration.nix#L185-196) admittedly indirect solution [from TLATER](https://discourse.nixos.org/t/how-to-use-packages-directly-in-allowunfreepredicate/22455/3) works:

```
{
  allowUnfreePredicate = pkg:
    builtins.elem (
      lib.getName pkg
    ) (
      map lib.getName [
        pkgs.corefonts
        pkgs.discord
        pkgs.jetbrains.idea-ultimate
        pkgs.spotify-unwrapped
        pkgs.unrar
      ]
    );
}
```

Comment: Doesn’t work in a flake’s inputs, because `lib` isn’t in scope.

Comment: At worst that means you have to replace `lib.` with `pkgs.lib.` in the above.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why your code fails is **not** because of `builtins.elem` (this works fine to compare strictly equivalent packages) but because of the fact that `allowInfreePredicate` is called on the **attributes** of the package (the `…` inside `stdenv.mkDerivation {…}`), and of course `stdenv.mkDerivation {…} != …`.

**How can you check/find it yourself:**

As a side remark, you can actually see if by yourself (I was not even aware of this before your question) using this simple trick to browse the great [nixpkgs repository](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs) (this is for educational purpose, it took me time to discover how one could go through the nix code efficiently… and it's really awesome to be able to read easily the code of a whole OS using a few commands! That's part of what I love with Nix!):

To that end first get [nixpkgs's code](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs). Advice: download it with

```
git clone https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs
```

in your home folder, it's quite practical to have it next to you!

Then, using `rg allowUnfreePredicate -C 5` (`rg` is a better grep that you should really install, `-C 5` displays 5 lines above/below, it's quite practical to see the surrounding text). You will directly see that `config.allowUnfreePredicate` is called in `nixpkgs/pkgs/stdenv/generic/check-meta.nix` ([here](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/c321a3bf252a8f919306d66a12326577f4802314/pkgs/stdenv/generic/check-meta.nix#L73)) to define a new function `allowUnfreePredicate`, itself called [here](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/c321a3bf252a8f919306d66a12326577f4802314/pkgs/stdenv/generic/check-meta.nix#L81) in `hasDeniedUnfreeLicense`, itself called into `checkValidity` ([same file](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/c321a3bf252a8f919306d66a12326577f4802314/pkgs/stdenv/generic/check-meta.nix#L358)) itself called into `assertValidity` ([same file](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/c321a3bf252a8f919306d66a12326577f4802314/pkgs/stdenv/generic/check-meta.nix#L378))… (yeah, it's a simple game where you just `rg` the name of the current function to find the next one ^^). This function is finally [outputted](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/master/pkgs/stdenv/generic/check-meta.nix#L391) from the file `check-meta.nix`. Using our friend `rg check-meta.nix` again it is not too hard to see that this file [is imported](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/0e125491647a8cb42cda08f82f91b65ad5e9c289/pkgs/stdenv/generic/make-derivation.nix#L6) from `pkgs/stdenv/generic/make-derivation.nix` as `checkMeta`. Finally (admitingly this is quite a long journey, it's often quicker ^^') this function is called [here](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/0e125491647a8cb42cda08f82f91b65ad5e9c289/pkgs/stdenv/generic/make-derivation.nix#L435) with a parameter `args` that turns out to be the input of the `mkDerivation` function ([here](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/0e125491647a8cb42cda08f82f91b65ad5e9c289/pkgs/stdenv/generic/make-derivation.nix#L157)). Done ;-)

Comment: Upvoted for explaining why my attempt failed. The community found a solution to do the equivalent, so I'll be marking that as accepted.